# I want to add background color to vimrc but it's not working

Tags: vim

I am forced to run this in my vim editor everytime I work.

```
highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=black
```

What I want is for this to be automatic, I already have background set to dark but nothing is happening in vimrc. What should I do? Vimrc contents (first few lines)

```
syntax on
set background=dark
set ruler                     " show the line number on the bar
set more                      " use more prompt
set autoread                  " watch for file changes
set number                    " line numbers
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In .vimrc, replace

```
set background=dark
```

with

```
highlight Normal ctermfg=grey ctermbg=black
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make the changes permanently that you did in Vim then you have to write the code in .vimrc then open the .vimrc file and then place this line

```
set background=dark
```

and then save & close . then open the Vim and you will see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can right-click on the terminal window - "Profiles" - "Profiles Preferences" - "Colors".

You can add it from .vimrc with  `set background=dark`

Good luck